# How to prevent overlapping when moving meshes?

Tags: mesh, geometry, snapping, collision

Is there a way to prevent overlapping when moving meshes?
I'm trying to emulate the assembly of planks in a furniture or cut stones in a wall.

EDIT : It is a GUI manipulation that I'm looking for. A bit like assembling Lego bricks in realtime in Blender (thus there is no animation and there are no frames).

I tried rigid body but it only works with a simulation. It tried the limit distance constraint without success. And "snap to edge/surface" can lead to errors as soon as you work with round/beveled/subdivided shapes.

I'd like the movement to be stopped when the two bodies start intersecting.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: How many pieces are there? How do they vary? Are you likely to change some sizes in the future?

Comment: Thank you for your comment  !
Around a dozen pieces I'd say. Normally I shouldn't change a lot of their sizes but as it is during the design process of a furniture, there are always adjustments :)

Comment: Are you animating this manually? If so why don't you snap to face then set that as your final keyframe? Then go backwards on the timeline and set your start point with the plank above? If the bevel causes you problems with snapping to an edge, then why not choose which part of the bevel you want on the surface, then snap face to a suitable vertice on the bevel? Works for me.

Comment: It is actually not an animation but GUI manipulation. A bit like assembling Lego bricks in realtime in Blender. Thus there are no frames.
But thanks for the proposal. I'll edit the post to precise things.

Comment: Have you try using python and bounding box on your objects? This way you could manage the intersections. But of course It will require a bit of coding.

Comment: @b-pader I am not a specialist in python coding but I do understand coding and I'm not afraid to try. Can you please elaborate how it would work dynamically in the GUI?

Comment: Have you tried using rigidbodies?

Comment: From what i know, rigid bodies only work when animating. Not in the GUI. How do you imagine to use them?